# Variable Scoping in Python

Tags: python, variables, cluster-analysis, k-means, scoping

Currently, I'm writing a simple Python program for doing the k-medians clustering, however I encountered a problem which I thought related to the variable scoping.

Here is my clustering method

```
class Cluster(object):
    center = None
    points = []

    def __init__(self, center):
        super(Cluster, self).__init__()
        self.center = center


def manhattan(row_a, row_b):
    dimensions = len(row_a)
    manhattan_dist = 0

    for i in range(0, dimensions):
        manhattan_dist = manhattan_dist + np.abs(float(row_a[i]) - float(row_b[i]))

    return manhattan_dist

def cluster(dataset, cluster_centers):
    clusters = []
    for cluster_center in cluster_centers:
        clusters.append(Cluster(center = cluster_center))

    for point in dataset:
        last_dist = np.inf
        last_cluster = None

        for cluster in clusters:
            dist = manhattan(point, cluster.center)
            if(dist != 0):
                if (dist < last_dist):
                    print str(dist) + " " + str(last_dist)
                    last_dist = dist
                    last_cluster = cluster


        last_cluster.points.append(point)


    return clusters
```

result = cluster([[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [7,2], [8,3], [7,1]], [[2,2], [6,6]])

--

```
result = cluster([[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [7,2], [8,3], [7,1]], [[2,2], [6,6]])
```

and here is the output that I got

[image]

The problem is that, I had an issue assigning the value to variable "last_dist" and possibly "last_cluster" inside the clusters for-loop, the value hadn't seem to be updated at all according to what can be seen printed in the output, except for that one single iteration that it has a value of 7 before going back to be its original value "Inf" again. What is the root cause of this and what can I do with it ? Thank you

Comment: Simplify and isolate your issue, and you will probably figure it out yourself. It seems this code contains a lot of noise that is not relevant to the problem you talk about.

Comment: The indentation appears to be off, as what you posted is not syntactically valid Python. Also, since indentation plays a primary role in scoping, depending on what the actual indentation is, it may be related to your issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my indentation is correct, sorry it got messed up here on Stackoverflow, I pasted it without checking.

Comment: Since indentation is syntactically relevant in Python, it's important it be posted accurately.

Comment: I couldn't get the indentation right so I uploaded the image instead, Thanks for pointing out

Comment: That is worse, no one wants to retype all of your code

Comment: Ok, I reindented them now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What else do you expect to happen? Here is your code:

```
for point in dataset:
    last_dist = np.inf # this line is executed 6 times
    last_cluster = None 

    for cluster in clusters:
        ...
```

You only have 2 items in `clusters`, and 6 in `dataset`. Therefore, for each point (6 times), `last_dist` starts as `inf`. You have 6 `inf`s in your output, so that is working as expected. For the second cluster, `last_dist` is only printed if it meets your condition `if (dist < last_dist)`. It looks like it does this exactly once, which is why you get `7.0` instead of `inf`. Perhaps you have a bug in `manhattan()`?

Because

Comment: I expect the variable "last_dist" to be updated everytime the condition "if (dist < last_dist)" is true, however it seems to be unaffected until when it got updated to 7 then it went back to be Inf again, I just really don't understand why it went back to be like that, and why it hasn't been updated consistently in the first place

Comment: @OpalThongpetch Do you understand how loops work? You set `last_dist = np.inf` initially for every `point in dataset`. Perhaps you want to move that initialization outside of your for loop?

Comment: Ok I will ask a simpler question, why didn't the value "last_dist" get updated to 2 after the first iteration ? as it went inside the "if (dist < last_dist)" block and executed "last_dist = dist" ? if it went well it supposed to print out "1.0 2.0" but it outputs "1.0 inf" instead ?

Comment: @OpalThongpetch the `1.0 inf` is the part of the next point. Your first point, second cluster gives `10.0 2.0`, which does not satisfy your if condition. This is because `abs(1-6) + abs(1-6) = 10.0`, not `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. You're trying to find the closest cluster to each point. The reason you might be confused is because you're printing those infs in last_dist right before they're changed to the value on the left...